# PHP session and hide table with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, session

Is it possible to hide the table with **jQuery** if their is session present?

this is my **session code**

```
<?php
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    if($username == TRUE){
        echo "WELCOME ".$username;
    }else{
        echo "<div class='msg'>Please Log In</div>";
    }
?>
```

and in my jQuery I dont know what to put in **IF statement** so I put it like this

```
if(".msg:visible"){
  $('table').hide();
}
```

If possible I want to hide the table using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using jQuery try below code

```
if ($(".msg").length > 0) {
    $('table').hide();
}
```

Comment: what is the difference of you answer from the answer top sir? and which is better to use?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".msg").is(":visible"))
 $('table').hide();
```

Comment: what is the difference of you answer from the answer below sir? and which is better to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide the table when session exists (when msg is not visible), you can try this with jQuery:

```
if (!$('.msg').is(':visible')) {
    $('table').hide();
}
```

However, if you page reloads when your users log in, you could do it directly on the table without jQuery:

```
<table <?php echo $username == TRUE ? 'style="display: none"' : ''; ?>>
<!-- contents -->
</table>
```